# Align child element of flexbox with the child element of second flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

As you can see the `<p>` element in the first flex2 div is bigger than the first element in the second and third flex2 divs because the word inside the `<p>` element is longer. So I am wondering if I could somehow make it so that the shorter `<p>` elements take the width of the longest `<p>` element in order for all of them to be aligned with each other

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='flex'>
        <div>
            <p class='red'>John</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex'>
        <div>
            <p class='blue'>Caitlyn</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex'>
        <div>
            <p class='blue'>Booyakasha</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that with your html structure. You should wrap each first `p` element in a same `div`.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.red {
    background-color: red
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue
}
.green {
    background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
    <div class='flex2'>
        <p class='red'>Looooooooooong</p>
        <p class='blue'>Shooooort</p>
        <p class='green'>Meeeedium</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flex2'>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flex2'>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code was actually slightly incorrect so I've changed it. The thing is the divs with class flex are generated programmatically so I can't really change the HTML structure. So there's no way to make them align with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. Only 2 lines are needed:

```css
.container {
  display: table; /*added*/
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*added*/
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flex'>
    <div>
      <p class='red'>John</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='flex'>
    <div>
      <p class='blue'>Caitlyn</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='flex'>
    <div>
      <p class='blue'>Booyakasha</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```